# What shall one do with questions which are obviously closed for the wrong reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

This might be related to using close reasons which do not quite fit, but what should one do when a question is closed with an obviously wrong close reason?

Example: [find middle point in c array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219796/find-middle-point-in-c-array)

In the specific example, the close reason used was `no-repro or typo`,
while the obviously valid reason would have been `duplicate`.

Comment: If they should **remain** closed, leave them closed. Perhaps, if inclined, leave a comment with your views on why it should remain closed and why the close reason is incorrect.

Comment: I face it once and i follow the same method and it worked.

Comment: when I see a close reason that may look very confusing for site visitors, I flag for moderator attention and point to this issue (suggesting a more appropriate reason if I can think of it); when my flag message is sufficiently compelling, moderators take care of that

Comment: @Oded: That's what I did, but already at the beginning of the closing.

Comment: There's a duplicate of this on the other meta stackoverflow.

Comment: If you had multiple people voting for close, maybe it isn't as obvious as you think?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Did you take a look at the question, and also compared the close-voters and the comments?

Comment: @Deduplicator: In the spirit of a Q&A database, I was taking the question as targeting questions of similar kind. It was not clear to me that you are seeking for a solution for that single question only. But even there, it seems that it was not obvious enough for the voters (that are not totally inexperienced, given the reputation needed for this feature), or are you implying that even though it was obvious to them, they voted?

Comment: Maybe I read your comment as directed a bit too much at me and the example question. Still, some of them in the comments said they voted to close with that reason, just because they did not like the question because it was a dupe. Edit: Ah, the comments were removed, only my part remains.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, it depends a lot on the specific situation and the specific question.

To quote myself in my answer to [Should we reopen a question if it is closed with a wrong reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208756/should-we-reopen-a-question-if-it-is-closed-with-a-wrong-reason) on MSE:

> In general, changing the close reason is a lot of work as you need 5 people to reopen and then 5 people to reclose it, and the 5 people to reclose it can't be any of the people who closed it previously, so you should leave it alone unless it is really necessary.
>
> However mods can do this on their own because of their binding vote, so it is preferable to have them do it. If something needs to be changed, you should flag it for moderator attention, using a custom reason and explain what you think should be done and most importantly why (but you need to be brief as you are limited on characters).
>
> Typically though this action should be reserved for cases where it absolutely needs to be done. The reason for this is because on busy sites, the you'd rather have the moderators working on more important flags. On slower sites, you have more leeway to do this since the flag queue is smaller.
>
> - Is the current close reason dangerously misleading?
> - Is the current close reason extremely confusing?
>
> So, in cases where an off-topic question is a duplicate of an another question, but the first question is closed for another reason, it is not worth adding to the mods workload when you can just leave an appropriate comment.
>
> But if a post is closed as a duplicate of a question that is not a duplicate (and the original still needs to be closed for another reason), it can confuse new users and new programmers, it is probably worth asking a mod to change the close reason to point to a more appropriate duplicate or closed for the correct reason.
>
> And in the cases where the just duplicate target needs changed (closed as a dup of question A, but question B is a better duplicate), the best solution now is to find a Gold Badge holder in one of the tags to edit the duplicate links to add a better duplicate, and remove any incorrect duplicates.

But to add to this answer, you may also enlist support in chat to get 5 people to help reopen and reclose the question.  This helps limit the workload for moderators since you don't need to involve them at all.

Comment: That's what I thought it would boild down to, including that the mods are busy enough. Still, there was no question here yet.

Answer (score 6):

Changing a duplicate target is easier than most cases, since it can be done by a single Mjolnir-wielding user, without getting the flag queue involved.

If you have the power, and you're certain of the duplicate, use it!

---

More recently, established users were given the ability to edit the list of duplicates -- so fixing a bad choice of duplicate no longer requires a reopen/reclose cycle.

Comment: Having the wrong duplicate target is the only case where having the wrong reason can be misleading. Other closure reasons ultimately say "thus question is bad and should be removed". Good duplicates are meant to say "if you have a question like this, look over *there* for the answer".

Answer (score -3):

Among the problems with leaving bad question closed for the wrong reason is that it sends a confusing signal to users (new and old) about what is and isn't appropriate for the site.  It makes it difficult for someone who asked a marginal question to know what to change in order to improve the question.

I'm not saying that leaving a bad question open is better.  It seems to me we need a more graceful way to "fix" the close reasons.