# Why is this Java question marked as a duplicate of this C# question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I was looking at this question, as I was wondering how to get the stack trace without intentionally throwing an exception:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/6210039/2171147

It's a question about [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) (specifically within [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)).

It got marked as a duplicate, and the top of the question says:

> This question already has an answer here:
>
> [How can I get the current stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/how-can-i-get-the-current-stack-trace) 12 answers

But when I click on that link, I'm taken to the same question being asked about [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net). Why does this make any sense?

Now, it *just so happens* that the line of code you run in .NET to get the current stack trace is the same you run in Java to do the same, but this doesn't seem like the correct behavior for the site.

Is this a bug ? Bad flagging? What happened here?

Comment: I guess that the only difference between the answers is the "get" in the method name. Though it is strange that duplicates cross languages.

Comment: And because it might be bad flagging, this is related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251673/what-shall-one-do-with-questions-which-are-obviously-closed-for-the-wrong-reason

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you closely look at the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java), It was originally tagged under `java`, later a user edited and removed the `Java` tag and added C# tag. See the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1069066/revisions)

The linked question doesn't even have valid C# code. I have rolled back the question.

Comment: @gunr2171, surprisingly that edit was approved by three users. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6099702

Comment: How do you formally request a review ban, and how do you know it's been actioned on? @gunr2171

Comment: @CarlAnderson You don't. You let the system take care of it. But if it's _really_ serious you can flag the post, use the "other", and explain your case to the moderators.

Comment: @gunr2171: The edit was fine. [bjb568 made a terrible edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1069066/7) before that, which changed the question from Java to C#. Therefore review bans aren't justified.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer, I agree with you. bjb568's edit was completely incorrect. The only thing I can say about the suggested edit is that the editor should have looked at the edit history, but that can be overlooked. Therefore I will rescind my comment (and delete it).

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer It wasn't necessarily a terrible edit. There is a debate that's been going on for 6 years about whether or not information that would otherwise come from your tags should be in the title.

Comment: @corsiKa: I wasn't talking about the title but the first sentence. "Like ... in .Net" changed to "in .Net".

Comment: The suggested edit page behavior looks like a bug to me, I [made a post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276389/3764814) about that.

Comment: These three who approved the edit should get a review-ban in my opinion: http://puu.sh/cJsWK/c3823cedf2.png. It was obvious from the question that this was about Java, not C#.

Comment: @cybermonkey no, it was not obvious **after** bjb's terrible edit.  After that terrible edit the "in Java" was no longer in the title.  The "edit approved" link looks like it might have a bug?  [see here for what was retagged](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1069066/7)  I mention this because someone reading your comment might get the wrong idea, if they failed to read the rest of this comment thread say.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Ah you're absolutely right. That... that is a terrible edit.

Answer (score 3):

The question had an approved suggested edit from someone who obviously didn't read the question, and it was obvious this question was about Java, not C#.

While simply *adding* the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) might have been acceptable (since the function the question asks about requires some knowledge of [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)), I do *not* agree that the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) should have been removed.

Although revision 8 edited the tags, [revision 7](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1069066/revisions) was the one that changed the scope away from [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) to [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).
In my opinion the user who [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2371861/bjb568) should have a review-ban.

Comment: About the review ban: see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276389/3764814). The reviewers actually saw a different question than the one you're seeing now ;)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Huh, that's true (and confusing). We'll just have to see how the bug report progresses.

Comment: also, another point: user changing the tags is actually the user who originally asked the question, so I doubt your claim "obviously didn't read the question" is true. The problem seems to be [revision 7 edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1069066/revisions) done by [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2371861/bjb568), which changed the content of the question from Java to .NET.

Comment: @eis Seems to be a bug in the Stack Exchange engine, as Lucas Trzesniewski pointed out. The edit shows that the question was `Java`, but the edit history does not.

Comment: There seems to be a bug, yes, but the bug only affects what we see now - it didn't cause the issue. The actual problem was the revision 7 edit, which looks malicious.

Comment: @eis Updated answer.