# Suggested edit review shows wrong post content

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, rollbacks

This is a follow-up of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276222/3764814) question.

When looking at a past suggested edit review, if the edit only changed the tags of the question, the review page will show the latest version of the post instead of the relevant version at the time when the edit was made.

Look at this case:

This [suggested retag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6099702) **appears** blatantly wrong, yet was accepted by 3 users. It changes the tags from [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) to [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) but the question clearly mentions Java:

> How do I get the current stack trace in Java, like how in .NET you can do `Environment.StackTrace`?

...or does it? If you look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1069066/revisions), at the time the edit was made, the question looked [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1069066/7):

> Can I get the stack trace `Environment.StackTrace` in .Net?

Which explains the suggested retag and why it was subsequently accepted.

This discrepancy makes the user who made the edit and the reviewers look like they don't know what they're doing. On the meta question which prompted this one, one user even wanted to request a review ban...

In conclusion, the suggested edit review page should always show the post version from the time the edit was made.

> ### **Please note:**
>
> This issue is **not** about whether the retag was right or wrong (this is handled by the [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276222/3764814)).
>   It is about what is **displayed** today vs what was displayed when the edit was made, and the  confusion this discrepancy generates.

Comment: The version that the suggested edit applies to was subsequently rolled back. This bug is probably caused by the rollback.

Answer (score 3):

There were a number of [problematic changes in an edit prior to the retagging](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1069066/7), such as removing "in Java" from the title<sup>1</sup> without adding it to the question body, and even more problematic, changing the .NET version from a comparative example to the goal of the question.

Someone needs a good talking to, and it's not necessarily the reviewers or the low reputation users.  Not a ban, since bjb often does a great job with edits.  More of the STOP! LOOK! THINK! variety that comes from audit failures.  Bad edits happen often enough (in absolute terms) even by high rep users that perhaps the site should have an intrinsic mechanism to vote to send a "WHAT WERE YOU THINKING!?!" message to a user with regard to a particular edit.

And I unconditionally agree that recalling review actions needs to show the post as it was at the time of review.

---

<sup>1</sup>We have a guideline that says "no tags in titles".  But this wasn't just stuck on a title, which is the problem that the guideline is meant to address, it was an integral part of the title and read perfectly naturally.

Also, that guideline is very commonly misunderstood.  It is NOT OK for information to be contained in tags only.  If information is getting moved from title to tags, or redundant between title and tags, an editor MUST ensure that information is in the question body before taking it out of the title.

Comment: *perhaps the site should have an intrinsic mechanism to vote to send a "WHAT WERE YOU THINKING!?!" message* – and/or [Jackie Chan reaction image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fNXeA.jpg).

Comment: Agh, I that people would assume a question is about Java if it were the only language tag.

Comment: @bjb568: Just don't remove information from title or tags if it isn't in the question body some way somehow.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok. I'll make sure to do that.