# Bad question closed for the wrong reason. Should I vote for reopen?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, vote-to-reopen

The question [How can I use grep to extract all IP addresses contained in all the files within a directory and sub-directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428243/linux-command-to-find-ip-addresses-in-all-the-files-within-the-directory-and-sub) looks pretty straightforward to me.

The first time I read it, I understood that OP wanted to find IP addresses that may be present in files contained in a folder and it's subfolders. Yet, the closing reason is "Unclear what you're asking".

Am I the only one to understand what OP wants at first sight?

**Edit:** It was on the Re-open queue

Comment: Well, he doesn't show any work that he's tried. This seems like a classic "do my work for me" question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That's not a requirement, nor is it a valid reason to close the question as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: But what he asks is still "clear", even if it's off-topic... It could be confusing for the user.

Comment: @resueman Re-open queue

Comment: @Patrice I don't see where this was written. He says "tell me how will i find IP addresses in all the files". And there was no edit.

Comment: @QuentinHayot fair enough, I paraphrased more than quoted.. should've quoted as this is indeed a clearer requirement.

Comment: @Stijn Is there not a close reason for "lacks a MCVE"? We could certainly re-open it and close it with a more proper close reason... Also doesn't seem like a programming question at all. Might be better off at Unix & Linux...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, I agree. But review when I review a queue, I look at the closing reason then at the post to take my decision. Should I vote "leave closed" even if the reason doesn't make sense ?

Comment: Missed the edit where you say it was in the re-open queue. To me, closing the question is the important bit. You could add a comment if the close reason is, ironically, not clear.

Comment: Audit-link: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9542589

Comment: *Is there not a close reason for "lacks a MCVE"?* - There is if the question is requesting debugging help.

Comment: I updated the title of this meta question to promote a constructive debate instead of a defensive post :)

Comment: Just want to through out that if the question should remain closed and it just has the wrong close reason we should leave it alone: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251673/what-shall-one-do-with-questions-which-are-obviously-closed-for-the-wrong-reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper response when you feel a question is understandable and yet find it closed as "unclear" is to [edit it for clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428243/linux-command-to-find-ip-addresses-in-all-the-files-within-the-directory-and-sub).

[image: Edit and Reopen]

Note that this also casts a reopen vote, thus ensuring that you're not only recording your own evaluation of the post but also altering it such that future reviewers will be more inclined to reopen as well.