# How to handle an incorrect close reason that could lead to more bad behaviour

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I recently came across a question that admittedly needed some work, but was closed very fast after being asked with a close reason that could very easily cause worse behavior.

The question is essentially asking for what algorithm should be used to solve a particular problem and I can see an argument for it being closed as Too Broad since the there are a multitude of ways to achieve the goal. The problem is the question was closed as Off Topic (General Computing) and now had this text attached to it:

> "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."

Since the user is new, the likelihood is higher than not, that this user may post their question on Super User as the text suggests which is guaranteed to be off topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779364/c-sharp-how-can-i-call-a-function-random-from-a-list-of-defined-functions

The question has since been deleted (it had other issues) but that was not the goal of my question. I would like to know what the best action would be to take (as a < 2k user) to handle this type of issue, should it happen again.

The possible answers I can think of are:

- Flag for mod attention, likely overkill and mods are busy enough
- Bring it to Meta, definitely overkill
- Bring it to a chatroom, could be difficult to find the correct room
- Ignore it and hope higher rep users resolve it, this just doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: That close reason sounds definitely *wrong*, especially considering that algorithms are on-topic here.  It really depends on what they're asking though.  We'd need to see a link to at least correct *one* wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Now, the question is simply not good, and while algorithms are indeed on-topic, what they're essentially asking for is too broad and too unfocused.

Comment: @Makoto  Fair enough that's the way I was leaning as well. The premise is good but definitely too broad

Comment: @Makoto does it need to be re-opened/closed for too broad? Seeing all the delete votes I have a feeling where this is going

Comment: @rene:  I'd say nuked, at this point...

Comment: Ok done, post is gone ...

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: If anything, it's a system design question that is on the borderline of being too broad.  I don't like the idea of assigning functions as proposed, but if the question was rephrased, tightened up and a 'cars on roads' design asked for, I would not down or close vote it.

Comment: Oh.. it's gone anyway.   I have been deprived of an opportunity to not close-vote:)

Comment: @Laurel That's good to know

Comment: @MartinJames I definitely would have like to have seen it cleaned up, its something I've implemented on more than one occasion and would have liked to post answer. Oh well can't win them all

Comment: @TravisJ I have nothing against the close reason on its own, in many cases it does make sense. In this particular case it could have prompted the user to create another question on a different exchange site that could never have been on topic at that community.

Comment: @Makoto - The close reason sounds wrong? It has been that way for years.

Comment: @TravisJ Again the close reason itself has nothing intrinsically wrong with it, the problem that I was attempting to address here is that the **wrong** close reason was chosen. As mentioned in other comments it should have been closed with a Too Broad reason

Comment: @TravisJ What everyone's saying is the close reason (general computing) is a good close reason, just not for this question.

Comment: @TravisJ You should read the the contents of the post before replying. In any case, I don't view OP's tone as malicious. Maybe a bit over the top (I interpreted harmful as meaning "dangerous" at first), but the intentions were good.

Comment: @TravisJ Not every incorrect close reason suggests that a user should ask their question on another community, that is why I chose to be more specific with my question. A lot of communities catch a lot of flak for just lobbing questions over the fence not realizing that they are off topic. That problem is more frequent with migration requests, but those at least leave a paper trail.

Comment: @Laurel I did hesitate a bit when choosing to use the word harmful for that reason. Its likely too late but I will try to come up with better wording.

Comment: @TravisJ:  Please don't misinterpret my statement; I meant that the close reason in the context of this *particular* question sounded wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may have been the result of a lack of consensus on close reasons. If there's no majority, it's the [last vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39664/323179) cast that decides what the banner says.

There are several things you can do:

[The post here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251673/what-shall-one-do-with-questions-which-are-obviously-closed-for-the-wrong-reason?rq=1) says:

> In general, changing the close reason is a lot of work as you need 5 people to reopen and then 5 people to reclose it, and the 5 people to reclose it can't be any of the people who closed it previously, so you should leave it alone unless it is really necessary.
>
> However mods can do this on their own because of their binding vote, so it is preferable to have them do it. If something needs to be changed, you should flag it for moderator attention, using a custom reason and explain what you think should be done and most importantly why.

If you're going to get 5 people together, it's probably worthwhile to go to chat. There's quite a few people there who wait around looking for things to moderate.

---

Personally, I think we should just remove the "ask on SU" text from the close reason. Did you know that web apps (for example) are off topic there? It's not what the text leads you to believe.

Comment: Do know the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room sometimes validates and when warranted  organizes those re-open/re-close actions, for example to close against a (better) duplicate. Doesn't happen often though.

Answer (score 6):

As a user without Close/Reopen privileges, the best thing you can do is comment.

Explain to the user why their question is not a good fit for SO, and if possible give them a hint on how to improve it. Encourage them to edit their question.
I often use the phrase "I suggest you [edit] the question", because `[edit]` is a magic link to the editing page.

Edits make a post eligible for re-opening. This is why it's important that an edit on a closed post is substantive; trivial edits will only make reviewers vote to "Leave Closed", and the asker misses an important opportunity.

Commenting and showing a new user how the site works is very valuable. If a bad question is closed, then re-asked on another site where it is closed again... then nobody is happy. The asker will think that SE is filled with jerks, and the members of at least 2 sites will feel their time is wasted.

So if you can spare the time to add a helpful comment and show the user how to improve their post... do it!