# What should I do when reason for closing changes in the reopen queue?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

I was going through the reopen queue and came across a question that was closed as unclear.

It landed in the queue because of an edit. This edit was significant and now it was very clear what the author was asking. The author obviously put some effort in it to vindicate the original close vote.

But now the question seemed to be off-topic, because it doesn't provide a minimal, reproducible example.

It felt I should have voted for reopen, but at the same time I should have cast a close vote for another reason. I ended up skipping it, but what would be the correct procedure?

Comment: strongly related, possibly even a duplicate: [What shall one do with questions which are obviously closed for the wrong reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251673/what-shall-one-do-with-questions-which-are-obviously-closed-for-the-wrong-reason)

Comment: Mine was closed for the right reason and the author took it by heart and put some more effort in it by editing. I would definitely be a reopen, it just happend to hit another close reason after the edit. So not really a duplicate.

Comment: Since the OP appears to be willing to put the work in to fix their questions, it might be worth pointing them to the Help Center and advising them to read all the pinned items if it hasn't been suggested yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the question hasn't been improved to allow it to be reopened, then it should stay closed.  Just because the close reason doesn't *quite* fit it anymore doesn't mean much; the intent is to keep the question closed until it can be made on topic.