# User edits my code and takes out the very thing I was asking about, I get downvoted, and they delete it

Tags: support

Can I message the guy and tell him what he did?  He took out what I was asking about and then there was no question what it meant.

Then the title had nothing to do with the code there. I get downvoted because people thought by double splat I meant a scope resolution operator.

If he had left it alone, it would have been a valid question and it was even answered in a comment before it got edited and then deleted as a duplicate.

Am I wrong to assume people know what a double splat is? I guess this guy thinks it's a double colon. I want to point out what he did

*https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52861672/revisions*

Comment: Any chance you can paste a picture of the deleted question here?  It would help greatly with helping you out.

Comment: or a link for the 10K+ users so we can see the pre and post edited question.

Comment: I don't know enough php to tell if the dupe is proper, but as for the edit, looks like they undid it pretty quickly.

Comment: It looks like they wanted to delete *EDit: spelling* and the the `**` in front of the `construct` keyword but realized they were wrong and rolled-back to the first revision. Based on the first comment and the dumplicates I can imagine tag followers would down vote for not useful.

Comment: The post existed for an hour before being deleted and was in its invalid state for less than 2 minutes. I suspect it it's most likely that it picked up the downvotes in the other 58 1/2 minutes.

Comment: I don't think it should have been deleted (yet) or closed as a dupe, but, it definitely seems quite a bit unclear to me. AFAIK `**`  means nothing in that context and shouldn't be there.

Comment: Right it is just invalid as  comment pointed out. I was wondering if it was some PHP 7 thing.

Comment: in that case the dupe seems invalid. not sure if it should have been deleted or not without at least an explanation it's just invalid code.

Comment: Ok.  it doesn't matter I guess. my question was answered. I will try to contact the person who posted that code on their blog and inform them.

Comment: my question was NOT about a scope resolution operator. It was about **construct.

Comment: In defense of the dupe it looks as though you're asking what the double splat is (ignoring the obvious syntax problems). there is no clarification of context here, so it appears to be a duplicate. *"What does the double splat mean in a situation like this?"*" Not, *"Why is this syntax, `::**`, in the construct?"*

Comment: This is also a good PSA for us to not hastily delete questions like this.  An hour is just enough time for me to post a question, go to lunch and come back to my desk to see it *gone*.  No sign post, no nothing.

Comment: @Makoto Except in your "deleted recent questions" section of your profile... :)

Comment: @Makoto, in all fairness a posted question with no response from the OP in over an hour makes it seem as if the OP abandoned the question. We see this all too often, especially when others start asking clarification questions in comments and there is no response from the OP.

Comment: @Makoto Also the fact that the OP didn't touch their question for *two* hours after posting it (not one), after getting feedback on it within minutes of posting it.

Comment: @HarryForbess You could have pinged me you know.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Not once the post is deleted.

Comment: @Servy right but they could have pinged me before, or undeleted it and pinged.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner They appear to have not interacted with the question at all until a while after it was deleted.  They also can't undelete a post they didn't delete personally.

Comment: FYI <https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design> is where I got that code from. I will let them know it is invalid. It was a simple question with a simple answer. If i post again, I will make sure and sit there to monitor the question until it's completion. I posted twice today and I regret them both. ONe was deleted and I wish this one would get deleted too.

Comment: @Servy Oh... right. I didn't know or have forgotten. See my side note under my answer. Gotta go!

Comment: @JayBlanchard:  This isn't instant messenger.  It's unreasonable to expect that an OP would be reactive within that window of time.  At *best* it's fair to expect them to get back to it within a day.  If they're more active then that then that's awesome.  But an *hour*??  Have you not been to any of the slower tags on the site?

Comment: @HarryForbess Most questions get the majority of their activity shortly after their posted.  Additionally, if the question has problems that inhibit its ability to be answered, they're quite likely to be brought up very quickly.  It happened within a minute in your case, and that's not atypical at all.  While you don't need to hover over the question for days straight, taking a few minutes, or even a bit longer, to look at the initial feedback to your question and ensure there aren't major problems inhibiting answers is time very well spent.

Comment: @Servy About not being able to ping me and to undelete. Thing is, the OP has been here long enough here I feel that they could have flagged their question to a moderator.

Comment: Note: I have flagged the question to moderators asking to undelete the comments between Devon and I. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @HarryForbess I have edited my answer, so please reload it.

Comment: @Makoto, from [ask]: "Post the question and respond to feedback 
After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!" I would say that leaving your computer after asking a question is not "ready to respond".

Comment: Now that everyone is aware of everything, what next? I believe the question should be closed, but as typo, not as dupe, and especially not as dupe to scope resolution operator (as explained in my comment on the question). Is there value in flagging a mod for that?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not expert in PHP but it looks like this is not a dupe, it should be closed as a typo. So the proper action would be to reopen and then close as off topic. Am I right?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251673/what-shall-one-do-with-questions-which-are-obviously-closed-for-the-wrong-reason

Comment: Since the question, as it stands, is about the double-splat the dupe is correct @TadeuszKopec If the question was changed as I suggested above, then perhaps we could close it as a typo. It's been around the horn so (it had been deleted) many times it hardly seems worthwhile to make change. It should've remained deleted as it is a very specific error caused by copying and pasting someone else's code. No matter how it is closed it should be deleted. As it says in the question you posted, *"so you should leave it alone unless it is really necessary"*. Dead horse is dead. Let it rest where it may.

Comment: I don't mean to carry on here, but IMHO, the [linked article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) should have been part of the question from the beginning. That way it could have been pointed out that the author(s) made a mistake. Only in comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375465/user-edits-my-code-and-takes-out-the-very-thing-i-was-asking-about-i-get-down-v#comment639120_375465) did we/I learn of it. If and when you post another question, please provide as much detail as possible, that way we can help to target it.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Yes, that would be the proper course of actions. If OP can't agree to have their question edited so that the dupe is correct, we should reopen and close as off-topic so it get roomba'd eventually.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The user that edited your question rolled back their own edit within a minute.  It was over an hour later that the post was deleted.

I think it's pretty safe to say that the editor realized they made a mistake with their first edit (since they corrected it right away), so there's no need for you to tell them that they did something wrong.

Additionally, it seems evident that the mistaken, and quickly corrected, edit had nothing to do with the deletion of the question, as the deletion took place so long after the edit was fixed, and because your question was in the invalid state for such a short period of time.

Comment: I was going to make a note of that in regards to the entire time frame all of this happened in, which I remember happened very quickly. I flagged my answer to moderators to see if they can undelete those comments or to edit my answer to contain what they were. Not sure what they'll want to do with it...

Comment: ...I want to add another note though that the OP did not tag accordingly (php only) if that was a Ruby/Python related question. Since I don't know the syntax used for constructs in those languages, I thought it was invalid and edited them out. That's when I saw Devon's comment about that and asked if I wrongly edited. That's when they told me about Ruby I think. In either case, I think the OP jumped the gun here. I did remedy it fast.

Answer (score 16):

That would be me and I apologized in a latter comment that I pinged [Devon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583522/devon) (as my witness) about, asking if I may have made a mistake, which he/she responded to and also deleted the comment.

If you ask a moderator to undelete the comments, you will see that I admitted I made a mistake.

So, I apologize for that (again) I made a mistake and I rolled back the question, also viewable in revisions.

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52861672/3

Edit:

I revisited the question in question and noticed there were 2 votes to undelete; I have casted a 3rd vote to reopen.

---

Edit #2:

> Am I wrong to assume people know what a double splat is? I guess this guy thinks its a double colon. I want to point out what he did

See the comments under [Servy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375467/1415724).

---

Mod edit - Screenshot of deleted comments on question as requested:

[image]

Comment: Btw, I was told about this meta question by someone I know. I don't follow meta a lot, so I can't always be watching what I did wrong. The OP could have pinged me.

Comment: To add to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375465/user-edits-my-code-and-takes-out-the-very-thing-i-was-asking-about-i-get-down-v/375467#comment639125_375467) under another answer would be, sometimes people use asterisks to make things bold, so I believe that that was the reason I removed them. If this is valid Ruby/Perl syntax, then I have learned something today. In pure PHP, the 2 starting characters are underscores which I've known for a long time, just not `**`'s. So, please pardon my ignorance. Yet, they should have tagged accordingly.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner your a nice person ;) that means a lot in my notebook also where are the adults clean up on aisle everywhere.

Comment: thanks @BobbyAxe *cheers*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: Just FYI if you want: It is not a valid Ruby/Perl syntax. Double-splat (which is indeed the Ruby term, both for the asterisk's shape and the action it does) is valid in a parameter list at method definition/invocation: `def tag(name, **attrs)` or `tag("a", href: "#", **attrs)`, or inside a hash literal: `{ name: "a", **attrs }`. (There is also `**` as exponentiation operator, but it's not called "double splat" in that usage.) I'm far from being an expert on Perl 6, but it only uses `**` in function definitions, calling it "unflattened slurpy parameter" (and exponentiation).

Comment: Thanks for the info on that @Amadan - I noticed your comment in the (Stack) question also about the `__construct` with the underscores, which is something I've always known since I learned some OOP in PHP. Either they found [that article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) that you linked to, or they found that somewhere else. In either case, I don't know what they're asking. The OP isn't responding anymore so I take it that they abandoned everything. *Cheers*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The article was linked by OP in comments to this (meta) question. They were asking what `**construct` was, without realising it was the blog author’s typo (there is proper `__construct` lower on the page) in a parallel example.

Comment: Ah yes, [I found/saw it now...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375465/user-edits-my-code-and-takes-out-the-very-thing-i-was-asking-about-i-get-down-v/375468?noredirect=1#comment639120_375465), I hadn't seen that, got lost in many comments, thanks. Yeah, that question was a typo from "the get go".

Answer (score 7):

> If he had left it alone, it would have been a valid question

No, not at all. The code in your question does not run. It's not valid PHP syntax. Had you bothered to run it, you'd have noticed it throws errors. Actually, leaving it, currently, does not make any sense, as the duplicate target is about the double colon `::`, whereas the code in the question is simply an off-topic typo question.

You have got it backwards: the edit made your question into a duplicate, instead of an off-topic non-runnable code one.

Answer (score -22):

The answer is no you can't contact the editor and you should forget about it since the question was answered before they deleted it.

Comment: Maybe not, but seeing that you've been here a while, I think you should have flagged for moderation instead. You can do that you know. The question's been undeleted by the way; I casted the 3rd vote to reopen.

Comment: Do know that on a non-deleted post you can @-reply editors but you have to type the username yourself, there is no auto-complete on it like with users that commented on a post.

Comment: how is this an answer? Did you want an answer when you posted this question?