# What is the appropriate way to handle a question closed for other reasons that is in fact a perfect duplicate of another question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64218927/364696) was recently closed for lack of focus (specifically, it was effectively a "write my code for me" question, although it was a case with a non-obvious, but very specific answer, which meant I didn't mind answering it since finding the answer on your own is surprisingly difficult).

I didn't find a proper duplicate initially (or I would have dupe hammered it), but on subsequent search found [a perfect duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31491379/364696). But by that time, the question was already closed for other reasons.

My question is how to handle this, now, and in the future. Options I can think of include:

1. Vote to reopen, dupe hammer when reopened (unlikely to work since the reopen queue doesn't allow me to explain reasons)
2. Flag with custom message to moderators (feels like hassling them for a relatively small problem)
3. Comment with link to duplicate (too easily buried)
4. Ignore it (don't like this option; would likely go with #3 if neither #1 nor #2 are considered appropriate)

Is there a specific course of action I should be following?

Comment: It really depends. Is it the umpteenth millionth duplicate of the target question, then no harm really comes from not marking it as a duplicate, since it has no lasting value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What shall one do with questions which are obviously closed for the wrong reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251673/what-shall-one-do-with-questions-which-are-obviously-closed-for-the-wrong-reason) (canonical is on MSE, that post quotes it, tl;dr moderator flag is a valid choice, but it's only worth doing where absolutely necessary, otherwise, commenting is the way to go)

Comment: I always wished the dupe hammer would override a previous close for this kind of thing.

Comment: @10Rep: In this case, it was relatively hard to find the duplicate (most of the questions that are easily found are round-robining `list`s of identical length, rather than `list`s of varying length where round-robining needs to continue with the longer inputs when the shorter inputs are exhausted). I've actually given the same answer to those other questions (because the general solutions works fine for both), but they're not duplicates, so this is not an "umpteenth million duplicate" case.

Comment: @Nick: I guess that answers my question in the broad sense. I'm thinking in this case commenting is probably fine; it still links the questions, and I don't disagree *enough* with "Needs focus" to say it doesn't apply.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately people are sometimes too trigger happy with TB/needs focus to try looking for duplicates, even though there's often one that applies

Comment: Why would you re-open something just to close it for a different reason? It's a waste of time and votes.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica: Because duplicate linkage specifically isn't just regular closure, it also directs the OP (and future people who find the OP's question) to the solution. All other forms of closure basically summarize to "you asked a bad question" with varying degrees of support for how to make it good. Duplicate closure is different in that it says "Your answer was already available, here, go look."